# How to map value to key?

Tags: javascript

Map will not accept dot notation for a key, how would you map a key from an array of objects to a key in a new object? For example I would like to convert:

this

```
searchResults = [{ _id: 'qEJBC9gED8knEKhHF',
  key: 'key1',
  value: 1 },
{ _id: 'KeoMTbpuCeuQMH8LJ',
  key: 'key2',
  value: 5 },
{ _id: 'Foy5pXbDbtLABmCxC',
  key: 'key3',
  value: 4 }
]
```

to this

```
[{ _id: 'qEJBC9gED8knEKhHF',
  key1: 1 },
  { _id: 'KeoMTbpuCeuQMH8LJ',
  key2: 5 },
  { _id: 'Foy5pXbDbtLABmCxC',
  key3: 4 }]
```

Example that does not work...

```
get_settings = function(doc) {
                return {
                  doc.key: doc.value
                }
            }; 
currentUserSettings = searchResults.settings.map(get_settings);
```

Comment: @Silicabello: Code + "does not work" != [MCVE]. Read the [MCVE] requirements please.

Comment: Ideally, you should post your attempt in the question *when you post it*, not after people ask you what you've tried

Comment: I really believe this problem is self explanatory without a code example...I added what you asked for, can we not get off topic here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with JS Array.Map prototype

Just use square brackets and pass in the value.

```js
var data = [{
    _id: 'qEJBC9gED8knEKhHF',
    key: 'key1',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 'KeoMTbpuCeuQMH8LJ',
    key: 'key2',
    value: 5
  },
  {
    _id: 'Foy5pXbDbtLABmCxC',
    key: 'key3',
    value: 4
  }
]

var mappedData = data.map(function(item) {
 return {
  _id: item._id,
  [item.key]: item.value
  }
});

console.log(mappedData)
```

Comment: Hi the key name itself needs to be the value from key in the first object array, this just removes the key value, and maps the value to a key called 'key'

Comment: Updated result.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!